# ResourceNotFoundException - String resource ID

Tags: android, textview

```
07-25 10:15:37.960: E/AndroidRuntime(8661): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String   resource ID #0x7
07-25 10:15:37.960: E/AndroidRuntime(8661): at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:230)
```

Good day to all.

I am trying to display an integer value in a Text View and the above error shows up in LogCat.

There are other similar posts about this issue; like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578618/resource-not-found-string-resource-id), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106708/android-not-found-resource-id), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676848/android-string-resource-not-found), but none of the solutions worked for me.

Any other ideas of what the problem might be?

**Edited for code:**

```
private static Button btnCancel;
private static Button btnConfirm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtRoomNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtRoomNumber);
    btnCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
    btnConfirm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm);

    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            finish();
            System.exit(0);

        }
    });

    btnConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {       
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            int rmNo = getRoomNumberValue();
            txtTesting.setText(rmNo);
        }
    });
}

private int getRoomNumberValue()
{
    int temp = 0;
    try
    {
        temp = Integer.parseInt(txtRoomNumber.getText().toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return temp;
}
```

Comment: show the code from where you are accessing the resource

Comment: textView.setText(Integer.toString(0x07));

Comment: Where in the code is the problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are trying to display an integer value in a `TextView`, use this:

```
myTextView.setText("" + 1);    // Or whatever number
```

The error happens because `TextView` has another method: `setText(int resid)`. This method looks for a resource id, which does not exist in your case. [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29)

Comment: This is the right answer.  Thank you for the help.  Will mark it as correct once I'm able to.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to set the content text of a TextView with an integer value.

The issue is that the method you are using is expecting a resource id.

You need to make a String out of your integer before putting it in the TextView :

```
textView.setText(Integer.toString(7));
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your Integer to String

```
textview.setText(String.valueOf(valueofint));
```

Comment: valueofint = your int variable

Answer (score 2):

To convert integer to string use

```
int x=10;
Integer.toString(x);
```

That will solve your problem